# Plotting symmetric density plot on a surface of a sphere - ColorFunction problem

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to plot a density plot on a surface of a sphere, where the density function `Sqrt[1-x^2]` is symmetric around `0`. (There, `x=Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ]`).

So far I have:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], 
Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Sqrt[1 - x^2]]]]
```

But somehow when the plot is displayed, the colors at `x=1` and `x=-1` do not match. Does it have something to do with the `ColorFunction`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], 
  Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 
  0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Sqrt[1 - x^2]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]